# How to insert selected SVG elements in a group with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am creating some svg elements with `javascript`, e.g.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');

// variable for the namespace 
const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

//assigning svg element attribute 
svg.setAttribute('class', 'layer1');
svg.setAttribute('xmlns', svgns);
svg.setAttribute('width', '400');
svg.setAttribute('height', '200');
svg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 400 200');

//make background
var fill1 = '#e6e6e6';
//var fill2 = 'transparent';

let bg = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect');
bg.setAttribute('class', 'bg');
bg.setAttribute('id', 'bg');
bg.setAttribute('width', '200');
bg.setAttribute('height', '200');
bg.setAttribute('fill', fill1);

// append the new rectangle to the svg
svg.appendChild(bg);

function createRect(a) {

    //create element
    var rect1 = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect');
    rect1.setAttribute('class', 'cl' + a);
    rect1.setAttribute('id', 'id' + a);
    rect1.setAttribute('x', '10');
    rect1.setAttribute('y', '20');
    rect1.setAttribute('width', '30');
    rect1.setAttribute('height', '30');
    //rect1.setAttribute("rx", "20");
    rect1.setAttribute('fill', 'red');

    svg.appendChild(rect1);
};

//create an array from  1 to 5
var bigArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    bigArray[i] = i + 1;
};

//create Rect for each element of the array
for (const el of bigArray) {
    createRect(el);
}

//create group
var group = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'g');
group.setAttribute('class', 'allRect');
group.setAttribute('id', 'allRect');

svg.appendChild(group);

var x = document.querySelectorAll('[class^=cl]');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body> 
    <svg>        
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I ask `javascript` to insert a custom selected elements `document.querySelectorAll('[class^=cl]')` (all 5 Rects) in a group `allRect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood the question (rough translation for me)

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
const
  svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
, fill1 = '#e6e6e6'
, svg   = document.querySelector('svg')
, bg    = svg.appendChild( document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect') )
, setSvgAttr = (el,attrs) => 
    Object.entries(attrs).forEach(([k,v]) =>
      el.setAttribute(k,v))
  ;

setSvgAttr(svg, { class: 'layer1', xmlns: svgns, width: 400, height: 200, viewBox: '0 0 400 200' })
setSvgAttr(bg, { class: 'bg', id: 'bg', width: 200, height: 200, fill: fill1 })

function createRect(a)
  {
  let rectN = svg.appendChild( document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect'))
  setSvgAttr(rectN, { class: 'cl'+a, id: 'id'+a, x:a*30, y:a*20, width: 30, height: 30, fill: 'red' })
  }

//create an array from  1 to 5
var bigArray = Array.from({length:5},(_,i)=>++i);
 

//create Rect for each element of the array
for (const el of bigArray) {  createRect(el) }

//create group
var group = svg.appendChild( document.createElementNS(svgns, 'g'))

setSvgAttr(bg, { class: 'allRect', id: 'allRect' })

document.querySelectorAll('[class^=cl]').forEach( elSVG => group.appendChild(elSVG))
```

```html
<svg></svg>
```